# Why this simple query breaks?

Tags: asp.net, database

I have a asp.net application, which save some users data using post form. For that I have a simple query listed below.

```
"UPDATE myTable SET LastUpdatedOn='"
+ DateTime.UtcNow + "', Completed='1' 
WHERE ID='" + requestid + "'"
```

This fails some times. But I think there are no issue with it. So please let me know why it happens.

Comment: Fails as in doesn't update or causes an exception? Help us to help you.

Comment: You should use parametrized queries. I don't know where your parameters come from but you may be exposed to a sql injection attack. I will also help you to forget about parameters format.

Comment: Is your ID column a varchar, does it take string text or is it an int? Most primary key columns are `int` and you are wrapping your value in quotes..

Comment: [Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/)

Comment: As the post does not contain what happened to `requestid` before the query, we shouldn't assume that it hasn't been properly escaped.  The `DateTime` should be safe as well.

Answer (score 1):

You should familiarize yourself with parameterized queries, and start using them to protect your system from [SQL Injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/).

```
using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand()) {
    cmd.CommandText =
        "UPDATE myTable SET LastUpdatedOn=@Time, Completed='1' WHERE ID=@Id";
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Time", DateTime.UtcNow);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", requestid);
    var count = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    if (count != 1) {
        Console.Error.WriteLine(
            "Warning: Cannot update myTable for ID {0}", requestid
        );
    }
}
```

As an added benefit, this approach eliminates all possible data formatting issues, and speeds up your queries by letting SQL Server cache query plans. But the main benefit is thwarting the attempts of "Bobby Tables" of the world to gain unauthorized access to your system.

Answer (score 0):

`DateTime.UtcNow` is not likely parseable to a datetime for the query.  Try:

DateTime.UtcNow.ToString('yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss')

(also, I may have screwed up my "m's", so double check it)

Comment: Although I would also suspect the date, that doesn't correlate to the "fails some times" statement. I was thinking that it simply doesn't update because the `requestid` doesn't match a record.

Comment: updates usually don't fail if they don't match any records though.

Comment: He has not quantified "failure".

Comment: Fair enough; I don't think an update statement not updating unmatched records is a failure, but I will admit I'm a bit of a purist on the subject.

Comment: I would also agree. I am more drawing attention to the poor quality of the question.

Answer (score 0):

insted of using `DateTime.UtcNow` consider to use `getdate()` if Sql Sevrer or simmilar function in whatever database you are using

```
"UPDATE myTable SET LastUpdatedOn= getdate(), Completed='1' WHERE ID='" + requestid + "'"
```

Comment: getdate() is sql server, which is not specified...

Comment: edit made - simmilar supported function in whatever database you are using

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure why this would break.  We would need to see the schema of the table to get a better idea of what could be going wrong.  On another note, I would suggest that you use parameterized queries instead of simply concatenating your query.  Your current query could be vulnerable to SQL injection depending on where the inputs come from.  Try changing your code to something like this to see if it alleviates the error (this will also mitigate the SQL injection risk):

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE myTable SET LastUpdatedOn = @LastUpdatedOn, Completed = @Completed WHERE ID = @RequestId", sqlConnectionObject);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastUpdatedOn", DateTime.UtcNow);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Completed", 1);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RequestId", requestid);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```